# Iterate through Superglobal with dynamic name

Tags: javascript, php, post

For a school assignment I have to build a client side shopping cart. The assignment states that I can only use PHP for sending the order confirmation. I am using hidden form fields (that are generated after iterating through cookies) to send the order details to a checkout page, where PHP will take over.

**The form fields on one page**

```
NumberOrdered = 0;
NumberOrdered = readCookie("NumberOrdered");

for (i=1; i <= NumberOrdered; i++){
    NewOrder = "Order"+ i;
    thisCookie = "";
    thisCookie = readCookie(NewOrder);

    fields = new Array();
    fields = dezeCookie.split("|");
    document.write("<input type=hidden name=\"ID_"+ i +"\" value=\"" + fields[0] + "\">");
    document.write("<input type=hidden name=\"BRAND_"+ i +"\" value=\"" + fields[1] + "\">");
    document.write("<input type=hidden name=\"MODEL_"+ i +"\" value=\"" + fields[2] + "\">");
    document.write("<input type=hidden name=\"MATERIAL_"+ i +"\" value=\"" + fields[3] + "\">");
    document.write("<input type=hidden name=\"PRICE_"+ i +"\" value=\"" + fields[4] + "\">");


}
```

Im having troubles iterating trough the values of the $_POST superglobal. I want to use a for loop that stores the values in an array. I am really doing this wrong though.

**After Submit**

```
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i > 12; $i){
    if(!empty($_POST["ID_$i"]) && !empty($_POST["BRAND_$i"]) && !empty($_POST["MODEL_$i"]) && !empty($_POST["MATERIAL_$i"]) && !empty($_POST["PRICE$i"])){
        $i = array ('id' => $_POST["ID_$i"],
                    'brand' => $_POST["BRAND_$i"],
                    'model' => $_POST["MODEL_$i"],
                    'material' => $_POST["MATERIAL_$i"],
                    'price' => $_POST["PRICE_$i"],
                );
        echo "$i";
    }
}
?>
```

Iterating through the $_POST superglobal does not work.. What would work?

Comment: By the way, I have a typo at !empty["PRICE$i]. The type is made during the writing of the question. In the actual script it says !empty["PRICE_$i]. So the typo you see in the question is not the cause of the loop not being executed or anything.

Comment: your for loop isn't ever going to execute, `$i` is initially set to 1 and then the loop's condition is that `$i` is greater than 12

Comment: Thankyou for your comment. I do not see this as an issue. I want to parse until $i is greater than 12, due to a max. amount of items allowed in the cart. And I start off with $i = 1, because the first value from the hidden field starts at 1. That value is retrieved from a cookie called NumberOrdered. This represents the number of items that are in the shoppingcart.

Comment: The condition in the loop is saying to continue executing the loop while i is greater than 12, but i starts out as 1 so it will never execute, i think you mean to use `$i <= 12` and then also increment `$i` within the loop e.g. `for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++)`, and also you don't want to assign `$i` the array you create inside of the loop

Comment: @MatthewMcveigh you are totally right. I messed up bigtime there. Thank you so much!

Comment: I managed to write it like: `$_POST['PRICE'.$i]` This solved it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Miss interpretation of concatenation:

```
$_POST['ID_' . $i], 
$_POST['BRAND_' . $i],
```

Alternatively if you always have the same number of fields with values, like, for sure, you could set name for each field as `ID[]`, and access as a normal array: `$_POST['ID'][0]`, `$_POST['ID'][1]`, `$_POST['ID'][2]`, ...

Though you have to be sure that all fields have some value. Empty, null or missing values will not be represented as empty value to `$_POST` and relation between data would be lost.

Btw, your `$i = array(...` would overwrite your own counting variable

And your `for` loop is wrong. You would never reach a loop, actually, because you have written: `for ($i = 1; $i > 12; $i++);`

Comment: Variables inside double quoted literal strings will be parsed e.g. `$i = 0; echo "ID_$i";` will output `ID_0`

Comment: @MatthewMcveigh But that is what he want. An array index based on an incremental value. He would be accessing `$i = 0; $_POST['ID_0']`

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear, what I mean is that php will evaluate `'ID_' . $i` and `"ID_$i"` to the same string so the concatenation shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Erm... it has a logical problem actually. His for will never reach something: `for($i = 1; $i > 12; $i++);`

Comment: I managed to write it like: `$_POST['PRICE'.$i]` This solved it for me.